# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void lstToUpdate(OrderItem) from the type TNV_OrderItemHelper

Tags: apex

```
public static void calculateunbilledCrdtAmtForPriceRamps(List<OrderItem> lstNewOrdItem, Map<Id, OrderItem> oldOrdItmMap){
    List<OrderItem> lstToUpdate = new List<OrderItem>();
      Decimal totalELP;
      Decimal totalTerms;
      Decimal unBilledTerm;
      Decimal billedTerm;
    
      for (OrderItem objOrderItem : lstNewOrdItem ){
        if ( objOrderItem.Order_Validation_Status__c != oldOrdItmMap.get(objOrderItem.ID).Order_Validation_Status__c &&
            objOrderItem.Order_Validation_Status__c == 'Success'){
                      //Some code to evaluate the amount/value
                    }
                    lstToUpdate(objOrderItem); //Here is the error popping.
                }   
            }
    }
    
    if(!lstToUpdate.isEmpty()){
        update lstToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems very obvious the problem. What part of the error don't you understand?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `lstToUpdate(objOrderItem)` means "call a method called `lstToUpdate` using `objOrderItem` as input", but you don't have such method. That's why you got that error.

You defined a list of OrderItem `lstToUpdate`, if you want to add an element to the end of that list, you have to call the [`.add()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_System_List_add) method on the list's instance:

```java
for (OrderItem objOrderItem : lstNewOrdItem ){
    if ( objOrderItem.Order_Validation_Status__c != oldOrdItmMap.get(objOrderItem.ID).Order_Validation_Status__c && objOrderItem.Order_Validation_Status__c == 'Success'){
      //Some code to evaluate the amount/value
    }
    lstToUpdate.add(objOrderItem);
}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you so much :)

Comment: @AbhishekSrinivasanUS You're welcome, glad I could help. Please consider to mark helpful answers provided to your questions as accepted, to benefit the whole community. [Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) you can read why this is a good practice.